# Apache not running in xampp despite of port changes

Tags: php, apache, xampp, localhost

I have changed the port from 80 to 8080 in httpd.conf and 443 to 4433 or 4443 in ssl, but still nothing changes and Apache is not up running. and shows error:
[image]

I have checked the ports also, port 80 and 443 aren't in use by any other app but still I changed the port in case it works. Attaching the netstat SS below.
[image]

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer, Actually my php.ini file was missing. Some how the php folder was renamed to php7 and thats why Apache was not up for running. I renamed it again to php and things got well again.